# Issue with dateInput format in R Studio

Tags: r, bloomberg

I'm trying to input excel files with the naming convention:
"New FileName - June 06"

I've created an dateInput function:
 dateInput("dates", "Specific Date: ", format = "MM dd"),

And a fileName function that concatenates depending on what date was inputted:
 fileName <- paste("H:\New FileName - ", date1, ".xlsm")

Does anyone know how to make this work? Or does R studio not allow date inputs with MM dd?

Answer (score 0):

```
date1 <- format(Sys.Date(), '%B %d')
paste("H:\\New FileName - ", date1, ".xlsm", sep = "")
```

```
[1] "H:\\New FileName - June 07.xlsm"
```

Replace Sys.Date() with wherever your date value is coming from. 
You will need double \ since R uses \ as an escape character.

When using R you have to follow these guidelines for formatting dates
https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html